# What happens when there are several exceptions in flight, and how to catch them?

Tags: c++, exception

I wish I could be more explicit, but there are so many possible scenarios where there are several exceptions in flight -- all involving destructors, but still.

How does the behaviour differ from C++98 to C++17?

I dare to prophesy "there's no way to catch when there're several exceptions in flight".

Comment: please next time try to be more explicit, you could have noticed that the number of scenarios isnt that huge ;)

Comment: Since C++11 you have [std::nested_exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/nested_exception). It's still only one exception "in flight" though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might read doc of [throw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw).

> If any function that is called directly by the stack unwinding mechanism, after initialization of the exception object and before the start of the exception handler, exits with an exception, `std::terminate` is called. Such functions include destructors of objects with automatic storage duration whose scopes are exited, and the copy constructor of the exception object that is called (if not elided) to initialize catch-by-value arguments.

So `std::terminate` is called instead of having *"several exceptions in flight"*.

You might still have several exceptions, as long as they don't exits their respective function:

```
void foo()
{
    struct S
    {
        ~S()
       {
           try {
               throw std::runtime_error("in S");
           } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
               std::err << ex.what(); // "in S"
           }
       }
    } s;

    throw std::runtime_error("In Foo");
}
```

Comment: Emphasis on *directly*. As long as it doesn't escape the code called directly by the unwinding mechanism, you are fine. Thus the move from [`std::uncaught_exception()` to `std::uncaught_exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception).

Answer (score -1):

There are never "several exceptions in flight".

If an exception is thrown during unwinding, your program is terminated.

If an exception is thrown by a handler, the exception that precedes it is no longer in flight.

Comment: What's that then called? https://wandbox.org/permlink/S3p5bE0TVWlm9NzN

Comment: @Adler I guess it depends on what you mean by "in flight". [An "extra" exception can be thrown and caught in the same scope without affecting anything](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception), but to me that doesn't really count as being "in flight". That's the idea with your example. You're observing before any unwinding takes place. Are those exceptions "in flight"? Well, I guess it's up to you to define it that way. I wouldn't. A plane on the ground isn't "in flight".

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818, well then, why doesn't it terminate right after `std::uncaught_exceptions() == 1`  and one more exception is thrown?

Comment: @Adler thats the problem when you do have a specific case at hand, but dont include them in the question, comments really s**k at discussion code. I suggest you to open a new question about that piece of code.

Comment: @Adler Because, as I said, you're not unwinding yet.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica, where does the standard say that in this(https://wandbox.org/permlink/S3p5bE0TVWlm9NzN) case the program must eventually call terminate?

Comment: @Adler I don't have the standard to hand. Jarod quoted the applicable rule from cppreference.com; it shouldn't be too hard to map that to the relevant standard clause